# How to fix my USB?

Tags: usb-drive

I formated my USB drive on a ubuntu computer, after that my USB wont work on any computer. How can i fix it?. I already tried formating it on a Windows computer and it said that it was unable to do it.

Comment: How did you format it in Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you formatted to a Linux-specific file system (such as ext2, ext3, or ext4) or partition table type, and the Windows systems you're trying to use it on don't have the extension installed to read/write that format.  Try reformatting (after backing up any data on the drive, of course) to FAT32 -- and make sure you create a new MS-DOS type partition table when you do so.  The resulting format should be readable on any DOS/Windows computer since the early 1990s (DOS 6.0 had FAT32, and came out in 1989), and any Linux machine since at least 2010 (likely much earlier -- but I'm not sure when vfat support was added to the Linux kernel).

As a general rule, any storage device you'll want/need to take to multiple systems needs to have an MS-DOS type partition table and FAT16 or FAT32 file system, since FAT is the most universally supported format.

If the USB stick won't write on the Ubuntu machine it was formatted on, it's probably gone to read-only mode due to a damaged file-system; you may still be able to create a new partition table using `fdisk` manually -- be very careful, as this program has no safety net built in; it will happily erase your system hard disk volume if you choose the wrong device.

If it won't read *or* write on the machine that formatted it, just replace the stick.  They're cheap enough these days not to spend much time on, and that failure indicates a hardware problem.